# If $H$ is a subgroup of $Z_{n}$, prove that there exist $m$ a positive integer dividing $n$ such that $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n/m}$

Tags: group-theory

I consider the application $f$ from $H$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{n/m}$ how $[m]_{n}$ to $[1]_{n/m}$ , where $\langle [m]_{n}\rangle = H$. But I don't know if $f$ is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.   By Lagrange's theorem the order of $H$ divides $n$.  $\therefore n=m\mid H\mid\implies \mid H\mid=\frac nm\implies H\cong\Bbb Z_{\frac nm}$.

Alternatively, $\langle k\rangle =H$, where $k=\min\{t\gt0\mid t\in H\}$.

Or you could use $m$, as you began to do.  That is, $\langle m\rangle =H$, where $m=\frac nd$.

Comment: Did you use the fundamental theorem of abelian groups? :3

Comment: Perhaps.   I knew that $\Bbb Z_n$ is the only cyclic group of order $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your solution correctly, you start with a subgroup $H$ of $Z_n$.  Then $H = \left<[m]_n\right>$, that is, the subgroup generated by (the equivalence class of) $m$ in $Z_n$.  You construct $f \colon H \to Z_{m/n}$ by sending $[m]_n$ to $[1]_{m/n}$.

So my questions are:

- How do you know $H$ is cyclic?  Maybe you've learned that as a theorem already, or maybe this problem is a lemma in proving that theorem.
- What is $f$ on other elements of $H$?  You've only defined it on one element.
- How do you know that $f$ is a homomorphism?
- How do you know that $f$ is bijective?

I think you're on the right track, but these are some details that need to be fleshed out.